# Vue-Router Page reload with form submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to make a simple movie searcher to get familiarised with Vue but this thing is a pain in the ***.

The problem I have is that I'm using the same component for the majority of my routes because they all do the same work but with different info. So I thought it was a good idea to use path params to tell what kind of information it needs to fetch, all the other routes work fine but when I try to submit a form with the query that I need the API search for, the page does not reload so for the component the info is the same as in the previous route.

I have already tried with router.go() and it does not work. Also tried with beforeRouteUpdate and all its useless cousins but none of them work either.

Here is my code:

Router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import Detail from "./views/Detail.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/favorites",
      name: "favorites",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/results/:search",
      name: "results",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/detail/:id",
      name: "detail",
      component: Detail
    }
  ]
});
```

Cards.vue This thing is called by Home

```
<template>
  <div class="cardContainer">
    <Filters />
    <div
      v-if="$store.state.movieList.length > 0"
      class="cardContainer-container"
    >
      <Card
        v-for="(item, index) in $store.state.movieList"
        :key="index"
        :id="item._id"
        :title="item.title"
        :img="item.image"
        :year="item.year"
        :description="item.description"
      />
    </div>
    <div v-else class="cardContainer-container">
      Not fun
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "./Card.vue";
import Filters from "./Filters.vue";

export default {
  name: "cardContainer",
  components: {
    Card,
    Filters,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      path: this.$route.name,
      params: this.$route.params.search,
    };
  },
  beforeMount(){
    console.log("path", this.path);//this work when I change with the navBars Links, but not when using the search button

  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next){
    console.log("I hope this works", to); //This thing does not work.
    next();
  }
};
</script>
```

SearchBar.vue

```
<template>
  <form class="searchBar" v-on:submit="onSubmit">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" />
    <button type="submit">
      Search
    </button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "searchBar",
  data() {
    return {
      search: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
       // this.$router.go(`/results/${this.search}`) //does not work
      this.$router.push(`/results/${this.search}`);
      this.search = "";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

UPDATE:

I resolve it by adding a weird watch in the cards component and using @submit.prevent="submit" when submitting the search form.

cards.vue

```
<script>
import Card from "./Card.vue";
import Filters from "./Filters.vue";

export default {
  name: "cardContainer",
  components: {
    Card,
    Filters,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      path: this.$route.name,
      params: this.$route.params.search,
    };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log("path", this.path); //dispatch
  },
  created() {
    this.$watch(
      () => this.$route.params.search,
      () => {
         this.params = this.$route.params.search;
        //dispatch 
      }
    );
  },
};
</script>
```

I still want a cleaner way of doing it. If anyone finds it, please let me know it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When u submit a form, the native behavior is refreshing the page, so I think you should do this:

```
v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"
```

or

```
@submit.prevent="onSubmit"
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo, thanks for your answer. It works partially. During the first submission, it refreshes the page but if I try to search for another thing it doesn't reload at all.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read your question that closely but you might need to make router-view key based off the URL (which includes URL params) so that it's not caching when URL changes (by default it doesn't include url params)

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

You should also never have the app refresh, ever, even on form submits. You should also use the `.prevent` method listed in the other answer.

If you need to share data across multiple pages you can use a store instead of query params, or you can just [use the composition api to build an extremely simple store](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/home-rolled-store-with-the-vue-js-composition-api/) without complexity of vuex.

Comment: Hi @Tallboy. I already did the router-view thing. It works fine. My problem is related to the search bar submit that does not reload when just the parameters change. And I need it to reload if the parameters change.